# Execute a function without opening input

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed an input that allows me to select multiple files. In these selected files, I show the name and type.

In the class of name and type when clicking I hold that a function is performed, however whenever I click there the input is always open.

How can I prevent the input from opening when I click on the label to execute the function () function.

Can anyone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xrrje?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**HTML**

```
<ngx-dropzone (change)="onSelect($event)">
    <ngx-dropzone-preview *ngFor="let f of files" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
        <ngx-dropzone-label (click)="function()">({{ f.type }})
      </ngx-dropzone-label>
        <ngx-dropzone-label (click)="function()">{{ f.name }} </ngx-dropzone-label>
    </ngx-dropzone-preview>
</ngx-dropzone>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping event bubbling should do the trick for you.

```
$event.stopPropagation()
```

See your modified example [here ->](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bg3vhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)